# How to launch Twitter application in Android?

Tags: android, twitter

I want to create an `Intent` that would pass the text and URL to the update status action in official Twitter application? How to do it?

Comment: Did you try [this][1] one?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application

Comment: Whether the answers for TwitDroid or Twitters official application..I am confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a Look @ these links:
[Create an Android Twitter client](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/02/15/twitter-android/)

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861729/twitter-update-status)

Answer (score 0):

Use Twitter API for Android.Its easy and available in opensource API